# Type WriteableBitmap is defined in an assembly that is not referenced System.Windows

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, xlabs

I am trying to create a Windows Phone 8.1 project, but I got an error saying `The type 'WriteableBitmap' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'`, but I can't find that assembly anywhere.

I tried to let Visual studio fix it for me, but then it came with this error [image: Error from Visual Studio].

My using is set to

```
using eKomplet.Services;
using eKomplet.WinPhone8.Implementations;
using Microsoft.Phone;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

And one of the lines, that fails are `var bitmap = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);`, where it gets `PictureDecoder` from `Microsoft.Phone`

I am using these NuGet packages

```
Acr.UserDialogs               5.2.2
Acr.XamForms.UserDialogs      5.2.2
Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls   2.1.8
ExifLib.PCL                   1.0.1
MR.Gestures                   1.3.4
Newtonsoft.JSON               8.0.3
Splat                         1.6.2
SQLite.Net.Core-PCL           3.1.1
SQLite.Net-PCL                3.1.1
Xam.Plugins.Settings          2.1.0
Xamarin.Forms                 2.0.0.6482
Xamarin.Insights              1.10.6
XLabs.Core                    2.0.5782
XLabs.Forms                   2.0.5782
XLabs.IoC                     2.0.5782
XLabs.Platform                2.0.5782
XLabs.Serialization           2.0.5782
```

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**
In Reference Manager Assemblies -> Framework tells me `All of the Framework assemblies are already referenced. Please use the Object Browser to explore the references in the Framework`.
Assemblies -> Extensions tells me `No user assemblies were found on the machine`.
Projects just shows the projects in the solution.
Shared Projects do not show anything
Windows Phone 8.1 -> Core tells me `The Windows Phone 8.1 SDK is already referenced. Please use the Object Browser to explore the references in the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK.`
Windows Phone 8.1 -> Extensions shows me

```
Behaviors SDK (XAML)                                          12.0
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for Windows Phone   12.0
Microsoft Visual Studio Test Core                             14.0
MSTest for Managed Projects                                   14.0
SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1                                  3.13.0
```

Browse shows me nothing

**UPDATE 2**
The problem also occurs in `App.xaml.cs` for this line `new XFormsAppWP().Init(this);`, so I think it must be something related to [this XLabs issue](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/1102). But did anyone find a fix or workaround for it?

**UPDATE 3**
I have used `PictureDecoder` from `Microsoft.Phone`, but you can only use `Microsoft.Phone` in Silverlight projects. In Windows Phone 8.1 you have to use `BitmapDecoder`.

Comment: For writable bitmap you apparently need, according to MSDN "Namespace:   System.Windows.Media.Imaging
Assembly:  PresentationCore (in PresentationCore.dll))", so maybe check if you have PresentationCore.dll?

Comment: When I push on Add Reference and Assemblies -> Framework, All of the Framework assemblies are referenced, and there are neither anything in Extensions. 
The only place where there exist anything is in Projects -> Solution and Windows Phone 8.1 -> Extensions (where Behaviors SDK (XAML), Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package, Microsoft Visual Studio Test Core, MSTest for Managed Projects and SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 are)

Comment: Go to project, add reference, and do a search for presentation core. when it comes up (which it should) tick the select box and press okay. I think that should work.

Comment: No items were found :(

Comment: I'd suggest searching for System.Windows, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e', There were some results, but I don't have time to wade through them